# Rest API is redirects to error page on Android works as expected on iOS

Tags: android, ios, api

I am facing very strange issue on android when fetching data from https://electoralsearch.in/

I generate captcha using:

https://electoralsearch.in/Home/GetCaptcha?image=true&id=Mon%20Nov%2018%202019%2020:32:20%20GMT+0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time)

on both iOS and android

and try to search for user using:

https://electoralsearch.in/Home/searchVoter?epic_no=BLN4315024&page_no=1&results_per_page=10&reureureired=ca3ac2c8-4676-48eb-9129-4cdce3adf6ea&search_type=epic&txtCaptcha=sO4ZJC

The problem is it gives expected result in iOS but leads to error page in android.

https://electoralsearch.in/Error/ErrorPage

I neither own the website: https://electoralsearch.in nor have any idea whats going on behind the scenes.

I appreciate any help that could be provided. I am also attaching the code zip for android for you guys to have a look:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxnikqi4x7r8adz/Test.zip?dl=1

Use BLN4315025 as EPICID and state as Uttar Pradesh.

The iOS code for loading the captcha is:

````
func loadCaptcha(){
        let format = "E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (zzzzzz)"
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())
        if let url = "https://electoralsearch.in/Home/GetCaptcha?image=true&id=\(dateString)".URL(){
            let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
//                Print(data)
                if data != nil{
                    if let image = UIImage.init(data: data!){
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.captchaImageView.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }


and searching the user using:

```func searchEPIC(){
        self.endEditing(true)
        var epicId:String?
        var captcha:String?
        var errorMessage:String?
        func validateFrom() -> Bool{
            if let val = self.epicIdTextField.text?.trimmedString(),
                val.isValidInput(){
                epicId = val
            }else{
                errorMessage = "Please enter EPIC Id!"
            }
            if let val = self.captchaTextField.text?.trimmedString(),
                val.isValidInput(){
                captcha = val
            }else{
                errorMessage = "Please enter Captcha Code!"
            }
            if errorMessage != nil{
//                AlertController.shared.showError(errorMessage, "OK!", nil)
                Print(errorMessage)
            }
            return String.isBlank(errorMessage) ? true : false
        }
        if validateFrom(){
            let urlString =  String(format:"https://electoralsearch.in/Home/searchVoter?epic_no=%@&page_no=1&results_per_page=10&reureureired=ca3ac2c8-4676-48eb-9129-4cdce3adf6ea&search_type=epic&state=%@&txtCaptcha=%@", epicId!, self.selectedStateId!, captcha!)
            if let url = urlString.URL(){
                let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                    //
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.reloadCaptcha()
                    }
                    if data != nil,
                        let responseData = data{
                        Print(responseData)
                        do {
                            let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .allowFragments)
                            Print(result)
                            self.processResult(result)
                        } catch {
                            if let string = String.init(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8){
                                Print(string)
                            }
                            Print(error)
                        }
                    }else{
                        Print(error)
                    }
                }.resume()
            }
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: @tynn if I were getting any error log... I am just being redirected to https://electoralsearch.in/Error/ErrorPage
and I have already mentioned that I don't own the website... Thats a Indian Govt Website :P
I am just trying to get data from that...

Comment: @tynn I am sorry for confusion... updated

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the API, i am using same for my tool

https://rapidapi.com/myvotersadmin/api/voterid_details

Comment: Thats a comment not an answer. Please put that in comment. Moreover two reasons:

1. The api is paid
2. Returns cached data.